# How to only output data if other data is above 0

Tags: php

I'm currently pulling data from a database to deploy on my HTML page. I currently use this:

```
$sql = "SELECT item, count FROM user_inventory  WHERE identifier='".$steamhextoidfin."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  "<b>" . $row["item"]. "</b> " . $row[""]. "<br>";
      }
```

Now I was wondering how would it be possible for it only to output the "item" data if the "count" data is more than 0 (>0)

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Why not check for that anywhere? Additionally, be warned that your SQL query is vulnerable for SQL injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add where, so your code will looks like:

```
$sql = "SELECT item, count FROM user_inventory  WHERE identifier='".$steamhextoidfin."' AND count > 0";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo  "<b>" . $row["item"]. "</b> " . $row[""]. "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure two `WHERE` will work?

Comment: Looks incorrect to me. Should probably be a single where clause with 2 conditions. "where .. and.."

Comment: sorry my mistake. Edited

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I was nearly there :)

Comment: @Sanderson you are welcome

Answer (score -1):

You can do like below:

```
$sql = "SELECT item, count FROM user_inventory  WHERE identifier='".$steamhextoidfin."' AND count > 0";
```

Also you can apply a condition on the result- like below

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row["count"] > 0){
            echo  "<b>" . $row["item"]. "</b> " . $row[""]. "<br>";
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: `result->count`? What is this?

Comment: Sorry, My mistake, the condition should be inside while loop. Like - $row->count > 0.
Editing this. thanks

Comment: `fetch_assoc` fetchs array. `->` notation will not work.

Comment: I guess it's a bad day for me. Thanks again